# TensorFlow Serving: Update model_config (add additional models) at runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow-serving

I'm busy configuring a TensorFlow Serving client that asks a TensorFlow Serving server to produce predictions on a given input image, for a given model.

If the model being requested has not yet been served, it is downloaded from a remote URL to a folder where the server's models are located. (The client does this). At this point I need to update the `model_config` and trigger the server to reload it.

This functionality appears to exist (based on https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/pull/885 and https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/apis/model_service.proto#L22), but I can't find any documentation on how to actually use it.

I am essentially looking for a python script with which I can trigger the reload from client side (or otherwise to configure the server to listen for changes and trigger the reload itself).

Comment: better choice was not to use the config file at all, instead using the other pattern where we mention the model path and model name in the command line.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So it took me ages of trawling through pull requests to finally find a code example for this. For the next person who has the same question as me, here is an example of how to do this. (You'll need the `tensorflow_serving package` for this; `pip install tensorflow-serving-api`).

Based on this pull request (which at the time of writing hadn't been accepted and was closed since it needed review): https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/pull/1065

```
from tensorflow_serving.apis import model_service_pb2_grpc
from tensorflow_serving.apis import model_management_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.config import model_server_config_pb2

import grpc

def add_model_config(host, name, base_path, model_platform):
  channel = grpc.insecure_channel(host) 
  stub = model_service_pb2_grpc.ModelServiceStub(channel)
  request = model_management_pb2.ReloadConfigRequest() 
  model_server_config = model_server_config_pb2.ModelServerConfig()

  #Create a config to add to the list of served models
  config_list = model_server_config_pb2.ModelConfigList()       
  one_config = config_list.config.add()
  one_config.name= name
  one_config.base_path=base_path
  one_config.model_platform=model_platform

  model_server_config.model_config_list.CopyFrom(config_list)

  request.config.CopyFrom(model_server_config)

  print(request.IsInitialized())
  print(request.ListFields())

  response = stub.HandleReloadConfigRequest(request,10)
  if response.status.error_code == 0:
      print("Reload sucessfully")
  else:
      print("Reload failed!")
      print(response.status.error_code)
      print(response.status.error_message)


add_model_config(host="localhost:8500", 
                    name="my_model", 
                    base_path="/models/my_model", 
                    model_platform="tensorflow")
```

Comment: Great answer thanks! I was wondering if it's possible to do the same update to the model_config with REST API instead of a gRPC call. Reason is that I cannot define a channel with my host that is behind Nginx and API Gateway (Kong).

Answer (score 3):

**Add a model** to TF Serving server and to the existing config file `conf_filepath`: Use arguments `name`, `base_path`, `model_platform` for the new model. Keeps the original models intact.

Notice a small difference from @Karl 's answer - using `MergeFrom` instead of `CopyFrom`

> pip install tensorflow-serving-api

```
import grpc
from google.protobuf import text_format
from tensorflow_serving.apis import model_service_pb2_grpc, model_management_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.config import model_server_config_pb2


def add_model_config(conf_filepath, host, name, base_path, model_platform):
    with open(conf_filepath, 'r+') as f:
        config_ini = f.read()
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel(host)
    stub = model_service_pb2_grpc.ModelServiceStub(channel)
    request = model_management_pb2.ReloadConfigRequest()
    model_server_config = model_server_config_pb2.ModelServerConfig()
    config_list = model_server_config_pb2.ModelConfigList()
    model_server_config = text_format.Parse(text=config_ini, message=model_server_config)

    # Create a config to add to the list of served models
    one_config = config_list.config.add()
    one_config.name = name
    one_config.base_path = base_path
    one_config.model_platform = model_platform

    model_server_config.model_config_list.MergeFrom(config_list)
    request.config.CopyFrom(model_server_config)

    response = stub.HandleReloadConfigRequest(request, 10)
    if response.status.error_code == 0:
        with open(conf_filepath, 'w+') as f:
            f.write(request.config.__str__())
        print("Updated TF Serving conf file")
    else:
        print("Failed to update model_config_list!")
        print(response.status.error_code)
        print(response.status.error_message)
```

Comment: A small but very useful difference!

Comment: I followed both answers, the docker of serving has opened both 8501 and 8500 ports . still I found an error. 
`raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)`
`grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:`
`        status = StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED`
`       details = "Deadline Exceeded"`
       debug_error_string = `{"created":"@1568010109.337260837","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:8500","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1052,"grpc_message":"Deadline Exceeded","grpc_status":4}"`

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what is the difference between using `MergeFrom` and `CopyFrom`?

Comment: CopyFrom overrides current listings of available models with your new models.
MergeFrom adds models to current available models.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering this, how do you add the field of 'model_version_policy' to the newly added config?

Answer (score 2):

While the solutions mentioned here works fine, there is one more method that you can use to hot-reload your models. You can use `--model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds`

As mentioned here in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config#reloading_model_server_configuration) -

> By setting the --model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds flag to instruct the server to periodically check for a new config file at --model_config_file filepath.

So, you just have to update the config file at `model_config_path` and tf-serving will load any **[new](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/ee665381efc6450bd8dc1499d5f6c939263228fe/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc#L367)** models and unload any models removed from the config file.

---

Edit 1: I looked at the source code and it seems that the flag is present from the very early version of tf-serving but there have been instances where some users were not able to use this flag (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891282/invalid-argument-model-config-file-poll-wait-seconds)). So, try to use the latest version if possible.