# How to delete a model details from custom model config file used to load multiple models in tensorflow serving?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deployment, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

How to delete a model details from custom model config file, which is used to load multiple models in tensorflow serving?

I have impemented the code to add the tensorflow models in runtime to the tensorflow serving config file using above thread : [TensorFlow Serving: Update model_config (add additional models) at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54440762/tensorflow-serving-update-model-config-add-additional-models-at-runtime)

I have no clue how to delete any model from this config file using python as this config file has .conf extension and its in string format.

**This config file looks like this :**

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name:  "first",
    base_path:  "/models/first",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
    }
  },
  config: {
    name:  "second",
    base_path:  "/models/second",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
  }
}
```

Now how to delete the model named "first" from the above file during runtime using python code?

**input :**

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name:  "first",
    base_path:  "/models/first",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
    }
  }
  config: {
    name:  "second",
    base_path:  "/models/second",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
  }
}
```

some python code using grpc or google.protobuf, tensorflow_serving.apis, tensorflow_serving.config, to delete model named "first"

**output :**

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name:  "second",
    base_path:  "/models/second",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out the answer for my question. The file models.conf is in protobuf data format but its type is string. To edit the it, use google python package. first,  i converted this file into json format and then removed the particular model details and then again converted back to protobuf format.

**1. read models.conf file**

```
with open('models.conf', 'r+') as f:
    config_ini = f.read()
```

**2.convert it to the json format**

```
from tensorflow_serving.config import model_server_config_pb2
from google.protobuf import text_format, json_format
import json
name='first'

model_server_config = model_server_config_pb2.ModelServerConfig()
model_server_config = text_format.Parse(text=config_ini, message=model_server_config)
proto_to_json = json_format.MessageToJson(model_server_config)
proto_to_json = json.loads(proto_to_json)
```

**3.delete the required model:**

```
proto_to_json['modelConfigList']['config'] = [dic for dic in proto_to_json['modelConfigList']['config'] if name!= dic['name']]
```

**4.convert json back to protobuf string:**

```
json_to_proto = json_format.Parse(json.dumps(proto_to_json), message=model_server_config ,ignore_unknown_fields=False)
```

Please refer this documentation: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/

Comment: that works great, was about to figure out by myself but decided to google first. thanks! wonder why there isn't an api available for doing this already.