# Unable to reload the config file on the fly in Tensorflow serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am following the below link to create a script that reloads the config file of the tensorflow serving on the fly .

[TensorFlow Serving: Update model_config (add additional models) at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54440762/tensorflow-serving-update-model-config-add-additional-models-at-runtime/54455066#54455066)

But, I am getting the following error

```
raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
    debug_error_string = " 
{"created":"@1563280495.867330024","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file 
_line":3381,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1563280495.867323165","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":453,"grpc_status":14}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by assigning the port number 8500 while invoking the tensorflow server using docker container and using the same port number in grpc client.