# Invalid argument --model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to start tensorflow-serving with the following two options like on the documentation

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 \
    -v "$(pwd)/models/:/models/" tensorflow/serving \
    --model_config_file=/models/models.config \
    --model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds=60
```

The container does not start because it does not recognize the argument --model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds.

```
unknown argument: --model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds=60
usage: tensorflow_model_server
```

I'm on the latest docker image, 1.14.0 and the line is taken straight from the documentation

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config

Does this argument even work?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please try with latest release and check(tensorflow_serving = 2.4.0).Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config is talking about code that has not been released as a new version yet, which is odd. I will ask about that.

That package is generated from this source:
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/serving_config.md, it mentions the `--model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds` flag.

However, the same document for 1.14.0 has no mention of the flag:
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/1.14.0/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/serving_config.md

Try using the nightly tensorflow serving image and see if it works.

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 \
    -v "$(pwd)/models/:/models/" tensorflow/serving:nightly \
    --model_config_file=/models/models.config \
    --model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds=60
```

Comment: Many thanks. Will take a look at it and let you know!

Comment: I build myself `TensorFlow ModelServer: 1.14.0-rc0+dev.sha.34d9e855` and it seems to support the flag, but only if a `--model_config_file` file is passed as an argument too and is valid. If i pass --model_config_file pointing to a non existing file, I get error `unknown argument: --model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds` instead of the expected `cannot find model config`

Answer (score 0):

Just tried. Tensorflow Serving 2.1.0 supports it while 1.14.0 doesn't.