# Best approach to swap regularly and dynamically models in Tensorflow Serving during run time?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I have models in production that are served using the Tensorflow Serving framework.

I would like to start A/B testing with these models, and I am wondering what is the best strategy to start this type of experimentation here.

Specifically, I would like to be able to switch between different models dynamically every half an hour and the serve different predict responses for the same call from the gateway.

As per these discussions:

[TensorFlow Serving: Update model_config (add additional models) at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54440762/tensorflow-serving-update-model-config-add-additional-models-at-runtime/54455066#54455066)

and this documentation page:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config#reloading_model_server_configuration

I know that this is possible, however I could really make use of a practical guide to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much this will be helpful to you but sharing my experience :
If you are using GCP,  TensorflowServing polls model from GoogleStorage gs bucket
and picks the latest Version of the model

but to use same API TFX allows to use modelConfig which you mentioned above to use with configuration  `model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds` so based on this it will poll for your configuration and that way it will help for swapping the models for your test

and model config can be set as:
`model_version_policy { specific { versions: 1 versions: 2 } }`